# How to set coloumn background color in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

I would like to know which property should I use to set background color of column of DataGridView table at design time. I don't want to do it programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the property `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` to `false` in order to get your custom settings work.

```
this.myDgv.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
this.myDgv.Columns[ 0 ].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

This should work.

// EDIT: Ahh you don't want to do it via code, but the generel approach works also with the designer. The property `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` is a direct property of the DataGridView  and the color of column you set in the property `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on DataGridView -> Edit Columns... then choose your column, click on DefaultCellStyle. This will give you ... button there, click it and set style as you want.

Comment: I've already checked it. I've set "backcolor" in "Cell style Builder" window as "blue", but I'm not seeing any changes.  May I know why?